# LWC: Get UserInfo using Lightning Data Service

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service, userinfo

I am playing around with Lightning Web Components and I was wondering if there is a way to pull the `UserInfo.getTimeZone()` using Lightning Data Service?

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
import getTimeZone from '@salesforce/schema/UserInfo.getTimeZone';

export default class MyTestClass extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getTimeZone) timeZone;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Access Internalization Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_i18n)

```js
import { LightningElement } from ‘lwc’;
import TIME_ZONE from '@salesforce/i18n/timeZone';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    const timeZone = TIME_ZONE;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the `i18n` from? Is there an article that explains what is contained in `@salesforce`?

Comment: If you have an experience with Lightning Aura Framework, it is much more easier to deal with LWC. Salesforce dedicates the separate chapter of LWC Documentation for Aura Component Migration https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_introduction. Information you asked I found here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_gvps . Also, I've included link to i18n documentation page in the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree the ultimate solution for just getting the timezone for the browser is from the above, I think this needs another answer. The best way to do this is to call a wire service with an Apex class that uses the UserInfo Class to return the User object and any fields you would like from this. I stumbled upon this by looking for any information on the LWC components that are exposed that mimic the Apex UserInfo Class and I only found @salesforce/user/property and property is either Id or IsGuest.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/get-current-user.html

So as of Spring ' 24, the @salesforce/user implementation is a little lite on exposed data. It is still best to use an Apex Class and use an @wire to grab the User object of the logged in user.